# Passing DEFAULT value into new SqlParameter()

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, c#

How can i pass DEFAULT value into stored procedure in MVC4 .NET ?
I have this code

```
return Database.SqlQuery<Program>(
                "spGetProgram @p1,@p2,@p3,@p4",
                new SqlParameter("p1", (object)ID ?? "DEFAULT"),
                new SqlParameter("p2", (object)displayStart ?? "DEFAULT"),
                new SqlParameter("p3", (object)displayLength ?? "DEFAULT"),
                new SqlParameter("p4", (object)searchString ?? "DEFAULT")
            ).ToList();
```

I tried

- `"DEFAULT"` --> Error: Conversion Failed
- `null` --> Error: parameter was not passed
- `DBNull.Value` --> it pass N'' value but this Value is not DEFAULT

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround but it works only for one default parameter.

```
return Database.SqlQuery<int>(
                "spGetProgramsCount " + (searchString != null ? "@p1" : ""),
                (searchString != null ? new SqlParameter("p1", searchString) : null)
            ).First();
```

but when I have more parameters for example

```
return Database.SqlQuery<int>(
                "spGetProgramsCount" + (searchString != null ? " @p1," : "")
+ (searchString2 != null ? " @p2," : "")
+ (searchString3 != null ? " @p3," : ""),
                (searchString != null ? new SqlParameter("p1", searchString) : null), (searchString2 != null ? new SqlParameter("p2", searchString2) : null), (searchString3 != null ? new SqlParameter("p3", searchString3) : null)
            ).First();
```

I am getting

```
When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values.
```

and i believe it is because commas in the procedure, i don't know how to handle it :/

Comment: If you know the names of the formal parameters (as they were declared in `CREATE PROCEDURE`), you can use your approach if you call the SP slightly differently: instead of `spGetProgram @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4` do `spGetProgram @formalPar1=@p1, @formalPar2=@p2, @formalPar3=@p3, @formalPar4=@p4`. That way you can omit a parameter at any position.

Comment: And of course there's a simpler way: instead of `(searchString != null ? " @p1," : "")` you could do `(searchString != null ? " @p1," : " DEFAULT,")`.

Comment: I already rewrite it at database level but thank you, it will help in the future!